# How can I include elements inside input for search field

Tags: html

How can I include elements like **img** or others inside the search *input* field. I want the results like this one: [image: Image from Google Images Search]

I have tried and thought about this but *normally you cant put other code in the input tag*. Some put search icon there others search buttons and more. How can I do this?

Comment: If you are using `Boostrap`, check out http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups. If not, you have to place an image to the right of an input field and style the container so that it looks as if it would be one element.

Comment: this is a google image search. just to make sure, you want a result similar to the camera icon on the right side? or you want to be able to 'upload' images like this image search does?

Comment: No I just want the small camera image to be present within the search field. Like a search button, or a search icon

Answer (score 3):

If you use your browser's developer tools to inspect an example, such as the [**Google search bar**](https://www.google.com/), you'll see that they simply layer elements using absolute positioning inside a relatively-positioned wrapper.

```
.wrapper {position: relative;}
.icon {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;}

<div class="wrapper">
    <input ... />
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/je0ads1y/)